# Modifying a column in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table `test`

```
iD Name    ParentId   GroupID
-----------------------------
1            1        Null
2            1        Null
3            1        Null
4            7        Null
5            7        Null
6            7        Null
7            9        Null
```

How can I modify it to get the column `GroupID` like this:

```
 iD Name    ParentId   GroupID
 ------------------------------
    1            1        1
    2            1        1
    3            1        1
    4            7        2
    5            7        2
    6            7        2
    7            9        3
```

Comment: Literally you just want that exact result set or is there some logic you want to apply to a more expansive set of data?

Comment: @Yuck I need to extract the exact set for the same ParentId

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
; WITH CTE 
AS
 (
 SELECT iDName, ParentId, GroupID,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ParentId ASC) RN
  FROM Test
 )
UPDATE CTE 
SET GroupID = RN
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6f298/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE test SET GroupID = 1 WHERE ParentId = 1
UPDATE test SET GroupID = 2 WHERE ParentId = 7
UPDATE test SET GroupID = 3 WHERE ParentId = 9
```

Comment: +1 because the question didn't bother to explain any differently.